# Desplegar aplicación laravel y angular en heroku

Tags: laravel-5, angular, angular5, heroku, laravel-mix

Mi pregunta es como podría desplegar una aplicación SPA en angular que estoy desarrollando, y con un rest en laravel 5.4, cabe mencionar que los ambos proyectos los tengo separados, y mi duda surge allí como puedo desplegarlos en heroku, ya que antes he desplegado aplicaciones con laravel y Vue por ejemplo, pero vueJS como saben viene integro con laravel, y bueno se hace más sencilo, encambio en este caso tengo los proyectos separados, que podría hacer para desplegarlos en heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Te creas una cuenta en Heroku, desde el mismo panel de control conectas Heroku con GIT. abres cmd/terminal :

```
heroku login
```

ingresas email y luego contraseña. Luego creamos la app

```
Heroku create nombreApp
```

### *Otros comandos*

- `Heroku open` abre el link de la app
- `Heroku logs -t` muestra los logs de tu app en heroku

Cada vez que quieras subir los cambios, deberas hacer lo siguiente
`

- `Git .`

`//seleccionas la carpeta`

- `Git init`

`//inicio`

- `Git commit -m nombreDelComit`

> //nombre del commit, puede repetirse!

- `Git push heroku master`

> //sube todos los archivos a herokuApp